# Django REST Framework - Tutorial - Confused

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm going over Serializers (`serializers.Serializer`, *not* `serializers.ModelSerializer`) in the [Tutorials](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) and I'm confused about one thing.

First off, we serialize the data into Python native datatypes:

```
>>> snippet = Snippet(code="print('hello' + ' world'\n)")
>>> snippet.save()

>>> serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet)
>>> serializer.data
{'style': 'friendly', 'code': "print('hello' + ' world'\n)", 'language': 'python', 'title': '', 'pk': 2, 'linenos': False}
```

The problem here is, we're not sending over any of the *choice field* options in either of the language or styles fields.

If we take a look at the `serializer` object, then it includes all the choices we have:

```
>>> serializer
SnippetSerializer(<Snippet: Snippet object>):
    pk = IntegerField(read_only=True)
    title = CharField(allow_blank=True, max_length=100, required=False)
    code = CharField(style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
    linenos = BooleanField(required=False)
    language = ChoiceField(choices=[('abap', 'ABAP'), ('abnf', 'ABNF'), ('ada', 'Ada'), ('adl', 'ADL'), ('agda', 'Agda'), ('ahk', 'autohotkey'), ('alloy', 'Alloy'), ('antlr', 'ANTLR'), ('antlr-as', 'ANTLR With ActionScript Target'), ('antlr-cpp', 'ANTLR With CPP Target'), ('antlr-csharp', 'ANTLR With C# Target'), ('antlr-java', 'ANTLR With Java Target'), ('antlr-objc', 'ANTLR With ObjectiveC Target'), ('antlr-perl', 'ANTLR With Perl Target'), ('antlr-python', 'ANTLR With Python Target'), ('antlr-ruby', 'ANTLR With Ruby Target'), ('apacheconf', 'ApacheConf'), ('apl', 'APL'), ('applescript', 'AppleScript'), ('arduino', 'Arduino'), ('as', 'ActionScript'), ('as3', 'ActionScript 3'), ('aspectj', 'AspectJ'), ('aspx-cs', 'aspx-cs'), ('aspx-vb', 'aspx-vb'), ('asy', 'Asymptote'), ('at', 'AmbientTalk'), ('autoit', 'AutoIt'), ('awk', 'Awk'), ('basemake', 'Base Makefile'), ('bash', 'Bash'), ('bat', 'Batchfile'), ('bbcode', 'BBCode'),....
```

So my question is, why are we not sending over the `serializer` object. Why just send the `serializer.data` which doesn't include the choice options. How will the client side know which options is has to choose from?

I may also be confused about where the client side fits into this tutorial. Something hasn't fully clicked yet with how this works for me.

Comment: How will JS handle the `serializer` object? JS just need the data in `serializer`

Comment: But if we're creating a new instance, or even updating an instance, JS needs to know which options we have available for the choices. How does it handle that?

Answer (score 2):

### OPTIONS method

> The OPTIONS method allows a client to determine the **options and/or requirements associated with a resource**, or the capabilities of a server, without implying a resource action or initiating a resource retrieval.
>   — RFC7231, Section 4.3.7.

If you want the JS to have the [meta information](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/) on that resource, you may want to implement a OPTIONS method, have the JS process the meta data returned, and then adjust the form for creating a new instance.

If you follow the above-linked documentation for Django REST Framework, you'll be able to customize what's returned in the meta data to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, why django restframework is so confusing and complicated. I have made several Apis in other frameworks and had better control over them. But here I have to read the documentation a lot to understand but still not clear.For instance, see laravel Api framework,it is so handy and secure everything is cooked, therefore we do not have to think a lot for settings, importing etc, just have to focus on business logic and API response format.